# How to read File ID using google drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am kind of new to php, I am working with Google drive api to create folders and sub folders. I want to create folder and by reading its file id, i want to create a subfolder. Giving its permissions etc...

please help me.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

Comment: @KristerAndersson that tutorial uses the old client lib do you really think that will help or confuse him?

Comment: @Keister Andersson Thank you for the link, but i already checked it out. I want to get "file id" so that i can create children folders. I dont want to manually paste the file ID. So can you help me with this criteria?